# C# code using XmlDictionaryReader

Tags: c#, xml

I am receiving an xml document into a WCF service and want to verify a specific element/attribute in the document.  I can verify that the contents are being read in with:-

```
using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents())
{
    string content = reader.ReadOuterXml();
}
```

However, I now want to get the value of a particular attribute and element in the XML. I have tried `reader.GetAttribute("name", "namespace")` and `reader.ReadToFollowing` followed by `reader.ReadElementContentAsString`, but the values are always `null`. What am I doing wrong?

---

I've tried various combinations of

```
string test1 = reader.GetAttribute("retry_number", "ns1 location");
string test2 = reader.GetAttribute("ns1:retry_number", "ns1 location");
```

The XML defines the element in a different namespace as `<ns1:retry_number>1</ns1:retry_number>` where `ns1` has already been declared.

Other code tried is:

```
reader.ReadToFollowing("ns1:retry_number"); 
string test3 = reader.ReadElementContentAsString()
reader.ReadToFollowing("ns1:retry_number");
reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
string test4 = reader.Value;
```

Firstly I would like some success reading the element and then move on to the attribute. The test variables are always set to `null`, despite in the first step I can see the XML in the content variable when I read the outer XML.

Comment: show the exact code snippet: there is possibly a bug in your code. Rgds,

Comment: Does your XML have any non-default namespaces?

Comment: Can you paste the XML that your dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

[I hope this article helps you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/custom-asp-net-core-middleware-example/)

```
using (var xmlReader = requestMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents())
            {
                // Find the element for the operation's data
                xmlReader.ReadStartElement(operation.Name, operation.Contract.Namespace);

                for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
                {
                    var parameterName = parameters[i].GetCustomAttribute<MessageParameterAttribute>()?.Name ?? parameters[i].Name;
                    xmlReader.MoveToStartElement(parameterName, operation.Contract.Namespace);
                    if (xmlReader.IsStartElement(parameterName, operation.Contract.Namespace))
                    {
                        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(parameters[i].ParameterType, parameterName, operation.Contract.Namespace);
                        arguments.Add(serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader, verifyObjectName: true));
                    }
                }
            }
```